# A light-weight "database" which supports both offline and online syncing

Tags: database, synchronization

Appreciate any suggestions to pick a database (preferably JavaScript supported) which supports both OFFLINE ad ONLINE data syncing.

Answer (score 1):

[pouchdb](https://www.rethinkdb.com/) is an open-source JavaScript database that supports offline sync

pouchdb is:

1. Light weight[46KB (gzipped)]
2. Cross Browser (All major modern browsers)
3. Well Documented ([Guides](https://pouchdb.com/guides/), [API](https://pouchdb.com/api.html))

There is a nice tutorial [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronizing-offline-app-data-with-pouchdb/) for synchronizing offline app data with pouchdb